# target blank direto na URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, link

No meu site eu tenho um botão flutuante que tem uma imagem e me possibilita colocar um URL, porém, não tem a opção de fazer abrir em uma aba nova. Tem apenas o espaço para a URL.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer a função `target=_blank` direto na URL, tipo `www.meusite.com.br/contato=_blank`

Desta forma, mesmo sem ter a opção manual de abrir em uma nova aba, eu conseguiria colocar o `target=_blank` direto na URL e fazer abrir em uma aba nova ao ser clicado nesse link.

Existe isso?

Comment: Pode ser com JavaScript? Existe uma infinidade de formas de fazer usando Js...

Comment: Tente inserir: `javascript: window.open('pagina.html', '_blank')`

Answer (score 1):

A reposta curta é não. Isso não é possível porque uma URL é requisitada através da barra de navegação o navegador faz um GET e a sua página é recarregada completamente. O que significa que para o browser já é uma "nova página".

O que você quer fazer é abrir uma nova página á partir da sua página atual. Isso pode ser feito utilizando a tag 'a' do html:

```
<a href="https://www.exmaple.com" target="_blank">example</a>
```

ou dinamicamente com javascript

```
window.open('http://example.com', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Direto na url não vai ter como. A única forma possível seria você inserir um código javascript na sua página. Por exemplo, se você adicionar o código abaixo, toda vez que clicar em qualquer elemento de sua página `document` que seja um anchor `a`, ele irá abrir o link em uma nova aba.

`$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});`